# How to Extract Symbols from each text in vector in R

Tags: r, extract

I'm setting up a new project in R ,and i need to extract each symbol from vector  (Docs) , I wrote this code but it didn't work

```
pattern=c("=d","<3",":o",":(",":)","(y)",":*","^_^",":d",";)",":'(") 

 for (value in docs) {
   variable = sapply(value,function(x){ 
     i = which(patt%in%strsplit(x," ")[[1]])
     if (length(i)>0){
       paste(pattern[i],collapse=" ")
     } else{NA}
   })
   names(variable)=NULL
   variable
 }
```

Comment: It would help substantially if you edit your question to be reproducible. What is an example input that other people can try? What output do you expect from that output?

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you are looking for can be found using the package `stringr` and function `str_extract_all(Docs, 'symbol',simplify = TRUE)`.
If you mean each character `strsplit(Docs, '')` should be enough.

Comment: I would like to extract any symbols in pattern from Docs if found .